# Bitwise XOR in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, bit-manipulation, xor

I'm trying to get an application to XOR two hexadecimal values and output the result as a decimal value.

I have searched the Internet for an answer, but every result simply gives a true or false result.

The figures I am using as an example are

> ```
> Value 1 = 0F8F
> Value 2 = FB8E
> expect result = 62465
> ```

What should I do?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/csw1x2a6.aspx

Comment: The code in your question is nonsense. For multiple reasons

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the `&H` [hexadecimal literal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9cz43ek.aspx):

```
result = (&HF8F Xor &HFB8E)
```

> 62465

Comment: UV for actually performing an operation to get a result  ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can enter hex literals using &H, and you can use the Xor operator.

```
Dim Value1 As Integer = &H0F8F
Dim Value2 As integer = &HFB8E
Dim result As Integer = Value1 Xor Value2 'The content of 'result' is 62465
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked. Two values entered into two text boxes and XOR'd with the result output to another text box:

```
        Dim value1 As String = "&H" & input1.Text
        Dim value2 As String = "&H" & input2.Text
        resultbox.Text = (value1 Xor value2)
```